# How do I create a log file in R that includes the R code?

Tags: r

How do I create a log file in R that has the R code and execution times for each line of R code?

Here is a sample of the R code:

```
library(RODBC)
myconn <-odbcConnect("TD", uid="TD7949", pwd="")
Employee <- sqlQuery(myconn, "select * from TD7949.employee")
odbcClose(myconn)
```

I would like to see in the log file the R codes above as well as any messages related to each of the codes and the execution time for the SQL query.

Comment: perhaps `?savehistory`

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html). Maybe not exactly what you need, but could be useful.

Comment: I have tried sink function but it does not show the R code.  It only shows the execution/warning messages. When there is a message, I could not point to which part of the R code that message relates to in the text file that I've created from sink function. Thanks